# Backup and restoration of USB-modem functionality

Tags: 12.04, networking, backup, usb-modem, restore

The laptop with USB modem is in another city with my elder relative. The laptop has dual boot with XP and Ubuntu. Modem works in XP. The modem did work in Ubuntu but not anymore. I cannot fix the problem remotely.

When I visit her I will fix it. After that, I need a way to backup the functionality of the modem and more importantly, an EASY way to restore it. So easy that 65 years old non-geek lady can do it with me helping over the phone.

Update: now the system works, but I still do not have a way to easily (backup and) restore the networking in a case of failure.

Comment: On this site and others, there are various articles dealing with the problem of getting the Huawei E169 to work. You could read those from the WinXP system, storing any necessary files on a stick, and retrieving them from the Ubuntu system. Is this the sort of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Just a failsafe way to use ubuntu with usb modem.   I have gotten it to work beautifully, but the problem is it wont keep on working. I need a way to fix it in need that a 65 year old non-geek lady can do the fixing with me helping over the phone.